# How to return a value while waiting for mouse interaction in PyQtGraph in GUI Application

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, pyside2

I'd like to use a InfiniteLine in in pyqtgraph that moves with the mouse moving. Upon left-clicking the function shall return the xposition. I am able to retrieve the x-value on left-clicking and moving the InfiniteLine with the mouse movement. However I am stucked at simply returning the x position. I'd like to wait for the left click, as I want to repeat this procedure multiple times.

```py
def addVerticalLineAndGetXOnClick(self):
    def changePosVertLine(event):
        if self.sceneBoundingRect().contains(event):
            mousePoint = self.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(event)
            line.setPos(mousePoint.x())
    def onMouseClick(event):
        if event.button() == 1:
            self.removeItem(line)
            self.scene().sigMouseClicked.disconnect()
            self.setMouseTracking(False)
            mousePoint = self.plotItem.vb.mapSceneToView(event.scenePos())
            self.xPos.emit(mousePoint.x())
    penLin = mkPen(color = '#000000', width = 1)
    line = LRI(0.,pen = penLin, name= 'singleLineToGetXPos' )
    self.addItem(line)
    self.setMouseTracking(True)
    self.scene().sigMouseMoved.connect(changePosVertLine)
    self.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(onMouseClick)
    #wait to return after mouse click and return
    """???"""
```

Comment: Instead of returning the value after the mouse click, store it as some internal variable within your class so you can access it anywhere

Comment: Thanks, but what is the best way for the caller to notice, that the value has been set?

Comment: You could send a signal when you set the value.

Comment: I agree with @Heike, if you're using PyQt, you can send a signal using `pyqtSignal()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any convenient way to wait for a signal before continuing?

Comment: If you connect a slot to a signal, the slot is called automatically every time the signal is emitted. The slot can be any function provided it has the correct input parameters for the signal it's connected to.